# How to move windows when the top is hidden?

Tags: resize, budgie

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie, and sometimes when a window is maximized the bar at the top of the screen covers the top of the window, meaning I cant move it.

Is there another way to move/resize windows when the top is hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key, then click-and-drag a window using the left button of your mouse.

If <kbd>alt</kbd> fails, try with <kbd>super</kbd> (usually the key with Windows logo).